# Cloud9 上の MariaDB を削除したい

Tags: mysql, mariadb, aws-cloud9

1. cloud9のmysqlのバージョンの初期は下記の状態でした。

   ```
   mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.42, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
   ```
2. php専用ワークスペースの構築作りで、サイトを参考にmariadbをインストールして下記のバージョンになりました。

   ```
   mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.38-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
   ```
3. やはりmariadbはいらないという事が判明したので、元に戻そうとしたのですが、色々なサイトを参考にコマンドを打ってみたのですが、変更されませんでした。
   例：mariadbをremoveしたり、元のmysqlバージョンをインストールしようと試したりしました。
4. 現在、は2の状態のまま変更できずに困っています。

---

追記
`yum list installed mariadb-server` を実行した所、下記の表示になりました。

```
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
hashicorp                                                                                                                                 1196/1196
225 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

現状のmariadbはこちらです。

```
ec2-user:~/environment $ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.38-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
ec2-user:~/environment $  yum list installed | grep mariadb
mariadb.x86_64                        3:10.2.38-1.amzn2.0.1          @amzn2extra-lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2
mariadb-common.x86_64                 3:10.2.38-1.amzn2.0.1          @amzn2extra-lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2
mariadb-config.x86_64                 3:10.2.38-1.amzn2.0.1          @amzn2extra-lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2
mariadb-libs.x86_64                   3:10.2.38-1.amzn2.0.1          @amzn2extra-lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2
php-cli.x86_64                        7.2.24-1.amzn2.0.1             @amzn2extra-lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2
php-common.x86_64                     7.2.24-1.amzn2.0.1             @amzn2extra-lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2
php-devel.x86_64                      7.2.24-1.amzn2.0.1             @amzn2extra-lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2
php-fpm.x86_64                        7.2.24-1.amzn2.0.1             @amzn2extra-lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2
php-json.x86_64                       7.2.24-1.amzn2.0.1             @amzn2extra-lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2
php-mysqlnd.x86_64                    7.2.24-1.amzn2.0.1             @amzn2extra-lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2
php-pdo.x86_64                        7.2.24-1.amzn2.0.1             @amzn2extra-lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2
php-process.x86_64                    7.2.24-1.amzn2.0.1             @amzn2extra-lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2
php-xml.x86_64                        7.2.24-1.amzn2.0.1             @amzn2extra-lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2
```

！追記（6/19）
サイトや公式ドキュメントを頼りに試しているのですが、下記だけのパッケージのインストールで大丈夫なのでしょうか？

```
ec2-user:~/environment $ yum list installed | grep mysql
mysql80-community-release.noarch      el7-3                          installed  
php-mysqlnd.x86_64                    7.2.24-1.amzn2.0.1             @amzn2extra-lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2
```

Comment: 実現したいのは「MariaDB を削除」で間違いないですか？

Comment: 「追記（6/19）」は一体何が大丈夫なのか聞きたいのでしょうか？それまでの質問との関連が不明です。目的は`mysql`コマンドがMySQLにすることではないのですか？`mysql --version`であなたの想定通りのバージョンが出ればいいのではないのですか？実際に想定通りのバージョンが出るのですか？出ないのなら、ダメですし、出るのであれば、解決しているでいいのでは無いのですか？

Comment: すみません。追記する質問を間違えてしまいました。また大丈夫というのはこちらでmysqlが機能するかを試さずに聞いてしまいました。本当に申し訳ありません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

編集される前のタイトルで「mysqlのmariadbを削除したい」と言っている時点で、MySQL、MariaDB、そして、`mysql`というコマンドや`mysqld`というデーモンとの関係が理解できていないと思われます。そのため、何をしたいのかがいささか不明な質問になっています。

「mysqlのmariadb」と言うものは存在しません。存在するのは「MariaDBの`mysql`コマンド」です。まず、その関係性から整理します。

まずは歴史のお勉強からです。

MySQLはスウェーデンのMySQL AB社が作成したOSS(オープンソースソフトウェア)のRDBMS(関係データベース管理システム)です。その後、MySQL AB社はSun Microsystems社に買収され、さらに、Sun Microsystems社はOrcale社に吸収合併されます。こうして、MySQLはOracle社の物になりましたが、Oracle社は元々Oracle DBというこれまた有名なRDBMSを持っており、MySQLがどのように扱われるのかが不明であり、MySQLのコミュニティーでは将来の危機感をもっていました。そこで、MySQL AB社の創設者がMySQLをフォーク(OSSなので誰でも自由にフォークできる)して作ったのがMariaDBです。その後、Oracle社はMySQLの開発を一応継続しますが、それとは別にMraiaDBも独自に開発が進んで現在にいたります。

MraiaDBはMySQLとは別のソフトウェアですが、MySQLからフォークし、また、互換性を持つため、各コマンドやデーモンがMySQLと同じです。MySQLでは、クライアントとして`mysql`コマンドを使用し、サーバーとして`mysqld`デーモンを使用します。MraiaDBも同じく、`mysql`コマンドと`mysqld`デーモンを使用します。最新版では互換性のためにシンボリックリンクとして存在する場合もありますが、いずれの場合でも、`mysql`コマンドはMySQLもMariaDBもそれぞれが持っている(適用する)ことになります。そのため、(別フォルダーに入れるなど出ない限り)MySQLとMariaDBを一緒に入れることはできません。

つまり、「MySQLの`mysql`コマンド」と「MariaDBの`mysql`コマンド」と二種類の`mysql`コマンドが存在します。どちらであるのかは、MariaDB側はバージョン情報にMariaDBの表記ができるのでわかります。これらを踏まえて推測するに、「MariaDBの`mysql`コマンド」を「MySQLの`mysql`コマンド」に戻したいといううことだと思います。

では、戻す方法ですが、Cloud9の環境(たぶん、Amazon Linux 2)がないので、以下は**憶測**ですが、かなり難しそうです。`amazon-linux-extras`で"lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2"という拡張ライブラリのレポジトリを有効にしているかと思います。これにはMariaDB10.2が含まれるため、普通に`yum install mysql`を実行した場合、そちらのレポジトリにあるMariaDBの`mysql`コマンドを入れるようとしてしまっていると考えられます。"lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2"を無効にして、"mariadb"と"mysql"とついているパッケージを全て削除してから、再度`yum install mysql`とすれば戻せるかも知れませんが、PHPのために"lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2"を有効にして、"yum update"とすると、また、MariaDBのほうに置き換わる可能性があります。

もし、どうしても戻したいなら、

1. 環境を一度リセットする。(全部はじめからやり直す)
2. "lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2"を使わずに、PHPを入れる。

とするしか無いと思われます。

そもそも、データベースのサーバー側は何でしょうか？一般的に、データーベースのサーバー側とソフトウェアとバージョンは合わせた方が良いと言われています。MySQLだったとしても、標準で入っていたMySQL 5.7は古いバージョン(最新は8.0)ですし、わざわざそれを使わなければならない理由が不明です。まずは、使おうとしているデーターベースのソフトウェアとバージョンを調べ、それに合わせたものを入れられないか検討することから始めるべきかと思います。

---

実際にやりたいことが「MySQLの`mysql`コマンドを使いたい」だけというのであれば、公式のRPMパッケージを使うのが最適かと思います。例えば、MySQL 8.0のインストール方法は、下記が参考になります。(Amazon Linux 2は「EL7 ベースのシステム」になります。)

[MySQL :: MySQL 8.0 リファレンスマニュアル :: 2.5.1 MySQL Yum リポジトリを使用して MySQL を Linux にインストールする](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/ja/linux-installation-yum-repo.html)

※ 全体の流れは、[AWS EC2 AmazonLinux2 MySQLをインストールする](https://qiita.com/miriwo/items/eb09c065ee9bb7e8fe06)等が参考になるかと思います。

実際に使用する予定のMySQLのバージョンとあわせてください。なお、MySQL 5.7は2023年10月で延長サポートが終了するため、お勧めしません。

※ lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2のMariaDBとコンフリクトする可能性があります。うまくいかない場合は、lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2は入れないようにしてください。

Comment: すみません。知識不足な質問になりますが、環境のリセットは他の環境も含めてでしょうか？

Comment: ＞標準で入っていたMySQL 5.7は古いバージョン(最新は8.0)ですし、わざわざそれを使わなければならない理由が不明です。＞＞すみません。初期のMySQLの状態に戻したいと思いまして、このような質問をしてしまいました。

Comment: どこまでやったら初期化されるのかよくわからないのなら、[AWS Cloud9 で環境を削除する](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/cloud9/latest/user-guide/delete-environment.html)で全て消してから、やり直した方がいいです。

Comment: 結局`mysql`を使うのでしょうか？使わないのでしょうか？使わないのであれば、元に戻すことにこだわらず削除してしまえばいいです。使うのであれば、MySQLなのかMraiaDBなのかそもそもバージョンが何なのかから吟味すべきです。それによってはMariaDB10.2が付いてくる"lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2"を使うかどうかも検討する必要があります。

Comment: MySQLのmysqlを使いたいです。また環境を削除して、再度作り直したのですが作り直してもMariaDBのmysqlになっていました。

Comment: 作り直して、何もしていない直後からMariaDB10.2のmysqlになっていたということですか？lampは入れていないですよね？

Comment: 入れていないです。

Comment: そうであれば、Cloud9のデフォルトがMraiaDBのmysqlに変更されたのだと思われます。単純に過去のバージョンに戻すのは困難です。MySQLのmysqlを入れた方が早いでしょう。その方法を追記しました。

Comment: インストールの際に、参考サイト内ではhttps://dev.mysql.com/get/以降と出ていたのですが、mysqlのサイトはhttps://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/からだと思うのですが、その場合はyumのURLを記入すればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: ちなみにMariaDBの削除までは出来ました。しかし確認の為にもう一つ新しい環境を作りチェックしたところ、新しい環境にはMariaDBのままだったのでデフォルトまでは変わっていませんでした。

Comment: 参考サイトは全体の流れを掴むための参考です。参考サイトは間違っている可能性がありますので、正確なコマンドやダウンロード先は公式ドキュメントを確認してください。よくわからない場合は、参考サイトは一切見ずに、公式ドキュメントだけを見てください。

Comment: 「新しい環境にはMariaDBのままだった」のであれば、デフォルトがMariaDBだということです。

Comment: Amazon Linux を使っているなら、[MariaDB が推奨のようです](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-lamp-amazon-linux-2.html) 。 MySQL と MariaDB では互換性があるのでほぼ同じように使えます。ここで敢えて標準で入っている MariaDB を (手間暇かけて) 置き換える必要があるのかを今一度検討してみてください。 / MySQL に置き換えるのであれば、それ相応の OS 管理に関する知識が必要になってきます。