# MySQL Yum リポジトリの追加でリポジトリの優先保護により何も実行されないのはなぜか？

Tags: mysql, aws-cloud9

下記の質問から新しく質問を立てさせていただきます。
[Cloud9 上の MariaDB を削除したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/95255/cloud9-%e4%b8%8a%e3%81%ae-mariadb-%e3%82%92%e5%89%8a%e9%99%a4%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)

公式ドキュメントとQittaの記事を参考にしつつCloud9にMySQLのインストールを目指しています。

[MySQL :: MySQL 8.0 リファレンスマニュアル :: 2.5.1 MySQL Yum リポジトリを使用して MySQL を Linux にインストールする](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/ja/linux-installation-yum-repo.html)
[AWS EC2 AmazonLinux2 MySQLをインストールする](https://qiita.com/miriwo/items/eb09c065ee9bb7e8fe06)
[【AWS EC2】Amazon Linux2にMySQLのclientだけをインストールしてRDSに接続する方法](https://qiita.com/tamorieeeen/items/d9b2af588f1dfd43120d)

現在、MariaDBを削除しまして、公式ドキュメントのMySQL Yum リポジトリの追加からEL7 ベースのシステムのMySQLのリポジトリを追加しようとしているのですが、使用可能なパッケージがありませんと表示されたため何もすることがないというエラーが発生しました。

エラーの詳細はこちらです。

```
ec2-user:~/environment $ sudo yum install mysql80-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
300 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package mysql80-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

試したコマンドは下記のとおりです。

```
sudo yum install mysql80-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm
```

エラーの表示は使用可能なパッケージがありませんと言っているのですが、
リポジトリの追加のコマンドは上記で正しいでしょうか？

**追記:**
下記のサイトを参考にMySQLのリポジトリを追加した後にインストールを試みたところ入れることが出来たと思うのですが、確認してもらえないでしょうか？

[AWS EC2 AmazonLinux2 MySQLをインストールする](https://qiita.com/miriwo/items/eb09c065ee9bb7e8fe06)

```
sudo yum localinstall https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm
```

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.33 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

Comment: タイトルに「リポジトリの優先保護により」とありますが、質問ではそのようなメッセージが出ていたという情報もなく、「使用可能なパッケージがありません」「何もすることがない」「使用可能なパッケージがありません」というエラーが発生したという不正確な表現しかありません。要約せずに、エラーメッセージをそのまま質問に貼り付けてください。どこに対してどのようなエラーが発生したのか、正確には把握することができません。

Comment: すみません。エラーメッセージを張り付けて頂きました。

Comment: 「追記」以降は最初の質問とは別の質問になっていると思われます。あなたは「コマンド実行時のエラーの原因を知りたい」のではないのでしょうか？そうであれば、別のコマンドについて正しいのかどうか聞くのは、別の質問として聞いてください。

Comment: パッケージがインストールされているかどうかは、一つ前の質問でのやり取りで `yum list installed` を使えば確認できるはずです (あなた自身も実行しているはず)。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
No package mysql80-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm available.
```

これは、"mysql80-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm"というパッケージが見つからなかったという意味です。`yum install`でパッケージ名を指定した場合、レポジトリから探しますが、ファイル名やURLを指名することで、ファイルやURLからインストールすることが可能です。もし、レポジトリから見つからず、ファイルやURLとしてもパッケージが存在しない場合は上記のようなメッセージが表示されます。

実行するときに"mysql80-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm"というファイルが存在するか確認してください。手順書にも次のように書いています。

> a. MySQL Developer Zone の「Download MySQL Yum Repository」ページ (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/) に移動します。
> b. 使用しているプラットフォーム用のリリースパッケージを選択してダウンロードします。
> c. ダウンロードしたリリースパッケージを次のコマンドでインストールし、*platform-and-version-specific-package-name* をダウンロードした RPM パッケージの名前に置き換えます:

手順書通りしたのであれば、b.でファイルをダウンロードしたはずです。そして、c.で「ダウンロードしたリリースパッケージ」をインストールする書いています。つまり、ダウンロードしたファイルを指定して`yum install`するのであって、そのファイルが存在しないのコマンドを実行しても意味がありません。